# Web service replace SabreCommand

Tags: sabre

Sabrecommand web services unable to retrieve new hotel information (Content Services for Lodging).

Did sabre have any other method to retrieve hotel information (Content Services for Lodging) by using command line method ?

Comment: Do you mean the *SD format?